# how to construct dynamic DB connection

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to construct dynamic OLE DB conenction manager in SSIS(SQL server Integration Service).since im running the package in multiple environment i have to change connection manager in  multiple places.it would be greatful if im creating it dynamically.

Comment: Do you want to create the new connection manager in multiple place or just want to change the connection string of the connection manager?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it through expressions.

see here-http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/12/08/making-the-case-for-expressions-instead-of-parameterised-sql-and-vice-versa-ssis.aspx